# XSLT (Umbraco) if certain doc type

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have a menu generated in a Umbraco macro:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and @level &lt;= $maxLevel and (umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false() or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())] ">
  <li>
      <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
      </a>     
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In that foreach, I would like a if-statement that only accepts a certain doctype, and generates the respective li/a tags and inserts a param from that doctype in the href. Only thing I can think of, is something like this:

```
      <xsl:if test="$currentPage/Redirect">
        <li>
           <a href="{$urlRedirect)}">
              <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
           </a>
        </li>
      </xsl:if>
```

Where `Redirect` is the doctype, and `$urlRedirect` is the param.

Bear with me, this is my first day learning XSLT

UPDATE:
Heres the complete code so you can see it in context:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<!-- The fun starts here -->  
<!-- update this variable on how deep your navigation should be -->
<xsl:variable name="maxLevel" select="5"/>
<xsl:variable name="minLevel" select="4"/>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and @level &lt;= $maxLevel and (umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false() or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())] ">
    <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and @level &lt;= $maxLevel and (umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false() or 

umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())] ">

<!-- Here is where I want my if/else logic -->

      <li>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </a>
      </li>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <ul>

      <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/../* [@level &gt; 3 and @isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and (umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false() or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())] ">
      <li>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </a>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
<!-- The fun starts here -->  
<!-- update this variable on how deep your navigation should be -->
<xsl:variable name="maxLevel" select="5"/>
<xsl:variable name="minLevel" select="4"/>

<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and @level &lt;= $maxLevel and (umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false() or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())] ">
    <ul>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and @level &lt;= $maxLevel and (umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false() or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())]"  />
    </ul>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <ul>

      <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/../* [@level &gt; 3 and @isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and (umbraco.library:IsProtected(@id, @path) = false() or umbraco.library:HasAccess(@id, @path) = true())] ">
      <li>
        <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </a>
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
     <li>
         <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
         </a>     
      </li>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Redirect">
    <li>
        <a href="{urlRedirect}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Update. Forgot to mention that if it doesnt match the template Redirect, it should use another template. If it does match Redirect, its not suppose to use the another template.

Comment: Pseudo like: <xsl:template match="Redirect">random</xsl><xsl:otherwise>random2</xsl>

Comment: How can * filter out Redirect?

Comment: it will not filter out redirect but it will match on <xsl:template match="Redirect"> before it match on <xsl:template match="*">

Comment: Okay. But wont it match * after it matches redirect. Generating it the li/a twice?

Comment: Oh wait, I made I typo i my first comment. Its not suppose use another template if it doesnt match redirect. Its really simple. I just want my href-value to be different, wether its a redirect template, or any other template. If(redirect)>link1 - Else>link2

Comment: I can see the logic in your answer, but im having trouble integrating into my code. Ive updated my question so you can see the complete code. Are you sure u still can do it your way?